# MVC 5 Display Datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new in MVC. I have a datetime property and dataannotaion like the following:

```
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, DataFormatString = "{0: dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", HtmlEncode = true, NullDisplayText = "-")]
        [DisplayName("Last Update")]        
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last Update is required.")]
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
```

When in create page it show good. But when I submit, I got validation error message "The field Last Update must be a date", and the data can not be process. Then I must change input format to "yyyy/MM/dd" and without time for submit.

I am using @Html.EditorFor(). How to display date format (dd/MMM/yyyy) in create page with EditorFor(), and display datetime format (dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss) in index page ? Or how to pass validation when EditorFor value datetime format like (dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss) ?

Comment: You can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastUpdate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")`. Note also most of your attributes are not necessary. Remove `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)`, `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`, `ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true` and `NullDisplayText = "-"`. If you do want the browsers HTML-5 editor, then it needs to be ` `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastUpdate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date" })` but its only supported in Chrome and Edge

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use textbox to get the required functionality.This is the way which I have done.Check If it might be of any help:

Model:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [MyDate(ErrorMessage = "Date Of Birth cannot be greater than Today")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Of Birth Required")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDate, "*")
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate, "Date :", new { style = "display:inline;" })
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",new { id = "datepicker"})
```

In the View `"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"` is used for setting correct format to the date

I have used Jquery Datepicker and the code is below:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      //dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",(to display date in required format)
      changeYear: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      yearRange: '1900:2222',
      background: '#000',
      showOn: "button"
    }).css("display", "inline-block")
          .next("button").button({
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-calendar" },
            label: "cal",
            text: false
          });
  });
</script>
```